# "Nothing was returned from render"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a parent component and want to mock the child by doing the following.
I have a `__mocks__` folder which contains the mock of my child component:

```js
//ChildComponent.tsx
import React from 'react'
const ChildComponent = () => {
  return <div>ChildComponent Mock</div>
}
export default ChildComponent
```

My test file:

```js
//ParentComponent.test.tsx which will render the child
import ParentComponent from '@/components/ParentComponent'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'

jest.mock('@/components/ChildComponent')
it('renders correctly', () => {
  const component = render (
   <ParentComponent />
  )
})
```

The error I receive is: `ChildComponent(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

Has anyone faced the issue yet while testing?

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the `__mocks__`folder has to be in the same folder as the 'original' child component. So it has to be like this:

```
- ChildComponent.tsx
  - __mocks__
    ChildComponent.tsx
```

Only then Jest knows were to look for the mock file.